# Does the mongo shell support vi editing?

Tags: mongodb

I need to carry out some very tedious command line ops on my mongodb. Has anyone tried setting the shell editing to vi?
Would be very useful if I can search my command history and change/replace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the [EDITOR](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#envvar-EDITOR) environment variable to point to vi/vim and MongoDB will use it when you issue the `edit` shell command, or you can use the same `EDITOR` variable in `javascript` to override the environment value.  Hence you can add the setting to your [`.mongorc.js`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) file to ensure it is set as you wish each time without manual intervention.

Example from the `mongo` shell:

```
> EDITOR='/usr/bin/vim'
/usr/bin/vim
> db
test
> edit db
```

Which fired up vim for me as follows (abbreviated output for brevity):

```
  1 test
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/tmp/mongo_edit1449005704.js" [noeol] 1L, 4C
```

In terms of your command history, that is kept in the file  `~/.dbshell` (as long as you are using something newer than 2.2.0) and can be edited directly.

Something to note: you can use `Ctrl-r` to reverse search and edit on the command line (hit `Ctrl-r` again to go one match further back, `Ctrl-s` to go forward etc.), just like you can in modern BASH shells.  For a full list of the keyboard shortcuts, have a look [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/program/mongo/#std-label-mongo-keyboard-shortcuts).